# How to retrieve logout time

Tags: php, session, authentication, cakephp, logout

I have built a simple cakephp app with simple user authentication. It works. I have a problem when the user is idle for longtime, the app logs out the user. The user should log back to perform actions on the app.

My question is there is anyway I can save the time when the user was logged out.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you log the user out? It it's just a timeout, you can only aproximate the logout time, `$time_lastActivity + $timeout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ivanka,

what Thariama wrote seems to be quite sound. Nevertheless, if you need the feature to show the user status to others, imho you have to work with cron jobs and cake shells.

You would need:

1. Thariama's suggestion with the timestamps
2. The cake shell + cron job going over every logged in user. Once NOW - lastActionTimeStamp > maxIdleTime, log user out and persist timestamp.

Adding the second point has the benefit that other users do not see the logged out one as present/active, as it could be the case if you stick with 1. alone.

Depending on the size of your userbase, you can set the checking interval.
Another approach could be to implement some kind of client side timer (JS/AJAX) triggering a logout, which could be unreliable in nature, but should be even easier to implement.

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

On your server/application there will be a configuration setting which defines the idle time span after which a user gets logged out. With this knowlege (i am sure you know where to look) you are able to ddo the following

```
$time_span_to_logout_user = 600; // example 10 minutes
```

Everytime a user is logged in and requests one of your websites pages you simply store this timestamp into the db.

To get to know the loggout time you simply take this timestamp from the DB and add the `$time_span_to_logout_user` -> this is the user loggout time.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it on app/config/core.php:

```
Configure::write('Session.timeout', '120');
```

[Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/ro/compare/44/CakePHP-Core-Configuration-Variables) explains this variable depends on security level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, write your own [session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) and log the time using the gc and destroy fns

Comment: no need to write your own when cake has one already, extend maybe